# Backbone.js Models storing reference to Collection - memory leak

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks

[image]

I'm trying to debug a memory leak in my application. I'm using Chrome's "Heap timelines" and noticed that in the space of a couple of seconds, over 5000 objects were allocated, all the same Collection instance. Expanding the tree down, each Model has a reference to said Collection. Could this be my issue? Why does Backbone do this? Is it a known issue to look out for? (I know this lacks a hell of a lot of context)

Comment: I can't imagine this being an issue, since references are cheap. However, I can see how storing 5000 instances of anything on the client side becoming a perf issue. is there a way you could paginate on the server side?

Comment: @u.k This is my issue, I haven't got 5000 of anything. Data comes from a WebSocket, I listen out for it in my Model (which is part of said Collection) and then informs a React component to update it's local state. I'm only displaying a handful of UI items, but they change multiple times a second.

Comment: The question is what is the size of the collection at any given time. In theory models that are removed from a collection and have no reference in the code will be garbage collected. the question is do they have reference in the code (could also be implicit on the framework level - if there's a view that is accessing the model for instance)

Comment: @u.k I believe I _may have_ solved it. I commented out one line in the Backbone source: `// model.on('all', this._onModelEvent, this);` in this method: `// Internal method to create a model's ties to a collection.
    _addReference: function(model, options) {` It's obviously there by design, but it seemed to be wreaking havoc in my app.

Comment: Can you report this in the [backbone github repo](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues) so the maintainers can address it?

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at the prototype chain of your model/collection..? It looks that way. If you ended up with a huge prototype chain, Chances are, there's something wrong with your code/ plugins you're using. People have been using Backbone in production for a long time...

Comment: Are you binding events with `.on` instead of `.listenTo`?